# Keep cursor in cell after cancel in WPF DataGrid CellEditEnding event with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a cell in a data grid that I'm editing.  When the cell editing is over I'm using the CellEditEnding event in the grid to capture that and do some validation. If if the validation fails I need to leave the cursor sitting in that cell and not move on to the next cell.  As you can see I'm setting the cancel to true but all this does is keep the cell in edit mode and still lets the cursor go to the next cell.  I need a way to keep the cursor in the cell until everything is ok.

xaml:

```
<DataGrid Style="{StaticResource ApplicationTabDataGridStyle}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentContacts, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding AddressGridItemSelected}"
          x:Name="ChangeInfoAddressGrid">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
            <command:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                    Command="{Binding ValidateAddressRowCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address 1" MinWidth="60"
                            Binding="{Binding Addr1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            IsReadOnly="{Binding Data.AddressGridItemSelected.CanEdit, 
                                                 Converter={StaticResource boolToOppositeBoolConverter}, 
                                                 Source={StaticResource IsReadyOnlyProxy}}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="26" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>

    ...

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

c#

```
public RelayCommand<object> ValidateAddressRowCommand => new RelayCommand<object>(ValidateAddressRow);
private void ValidateAddressRow(object eventArgs)
{
    var cellEventArgs = eventArgs as DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs;
    // DO SOME VALIDATION

    ...

    cellEventArgs.Cancel = true;     
    cellEventArgs.EditingElement.Focus();
}
```

Comment: What is with another controls in your window, so if edit mode being finished through the click on another control in your window?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with `DataGrid_CellEditEnding` event handler and used dispatcher to reach the goal(I had a datagrid):

```
private void DataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    (sender as DataGrid).Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>
        {
            (sender as DataGrid).SelectedIndex = e.Row.GetIndex();
            e.EditingElement.Focus();
        }
    ));
}
```

You can adjust it for your needs. I'm confused, that you use View classes (`DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs`) in ViewModel.

Comment: I understand what you are doing but this does not follow the MVVM pattern.  I dont have the sender object available to me.

Comment: But you have `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs`, which also not MVVM conform.

Comment: You could move this eventhandler to a behavior with a `DependencyProperty` let say `ValidationFunction` and bind this property to the property from ViewModel.

Comment: @NormTheThird: Your issue has nothing to do with MVVM. A view model is not responsible for keeping a cursor in a cell of a DataGrid. This functionality should be implemented in the control or in the view that hosts the control. Referring a DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs in a view model is bad practise.